# Regex for string starting with quote but not with escape character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to find a string which start and end with double quotes and then change its color. But if there is escape character (/) with quote then it will not be considered as string and color will not be changed.

For example:

1. "hello"
2. \"hello\"

The first example will be considered as string while the second example will not be considered as a string.

How to write a regex in javascript which only returns a string which starts and ends with double quotes but there should not have any escape character (/)

Comment: Maybe `\\?".+\\?"` ? And `str.replace('\\', '');` for replacing backslashes?

Comment: in your explanation you have `/` this and in your input `\\` which one you want to match ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need a regex here - simple first character check with `charAt`:

```js
const strings = [`"hello"`, `\\"hello\\"`];
strings.forEach(s => console.log(s.charAt(0) == `"`));
```

If you really need a regex:

```js
const strings = [`"hello"`, `\\"hello\\"`];
const regex = /^[\"]/;
strings.forEach(s => console.log(regex.test(s)));
```

Comment: I need regex as I am writing the rules in a library.

Comment: @AnubhaGupta Edited with a regex, does this suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be using `JSON.parse()`, since a string like `"hello"`
is also a valid JSON object, while a string like `"hello\"` is not.

```js
function checkString(str){
    try {
        // let's try to parse the string as a JSON object
        const parsed = JSON.parse(str);
        // check if the result is a valid javascript string
        return (parsed === String(parsed));
    }
    catch(error){
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If you have an array of objects, and you need to find which object is a valid string, you can do this:

```js
const strings = ['"valid string"', '"not valid string\\"'];
const validStrings = strings.filter((e) => {
    return (e === String(e) && checkString(e));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern

```
^(?!.*\/)".*"$
```

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\\)` - condition to avoid any `\`
- `"` - Matches `"`
- `.*` - Matches anything except new line
- `$`  - End of string

```js
const strings = [`"hello"`, `\\"hello\\"`, `\\"hello`, `hello"\\`, `"hel/lo"`,];
strings.forEach(s => {
  if(/^(?!.*\\)".*"$/.test(s)){
    console.log(s)
  }
});
```